# How can I write a number inside a substituion string that has groups in the form \n without spaces?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a regular expression object and substitution code for a date formatter programme.

The simplified code is below:

```py
assembledString = myRegex.sub(r"\2\3\4\5\6", textToChange)
#Where \2 , \3 ,\4 etc. are the groups of my regular expression object.
```

So `assembledString` comprises of the groups put together, but I want to insert the number '0' between the groups '\3' and '\4'. However, when I do this, it is read as '\30', i.e. group 30. Similarly, when I leave spaces in the substitution string, such as r"\2\3 0 \4\5\6", the spaces also get inserted into the `assembledString`.

I have tried concatenating the substitution string as well as using escape characters as well as quotation marks but I haven't managed to find a solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\g<number of group>` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub)). From doc:

> ... \g uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is therefore
>   equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as \g<2>0.
>   \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference
>   to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'. The backreference
>   \g<0> substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

```
import re

s = 'This will insert 0 between AB'

print( re.sub(r'([A-Z])([A-Z])', r'\g<1>0\g<2>', s) )
```

Prints:

```
This will insert 0 between A0B
```

Answer (score 0):

It normally should not interpret this way, but if you have tried everything else, and adding a little bit of time to the run is not a problem, try doing this in two steps.

First, you add not only '0', but also some weird word that cannot be found anywhere else, and next, you replace only the word with null ''.

```
## r"\2\3WEIRD0\4\5\6"
then use [WEIRD] in regex and delete it from assembled_string.
```